# How to build an array in the order from one array and rank from another in typescript?

Tags: javascript, react-typescript

I have the following array, which has the desired order.

```
main_array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

From a specific process, I get another array containing only 3 elements in `main_array`, but it may have the elements in any order.

```
subset_array = ['d', 'a', 'f']
```

From these two arrays, I need to create an array with the ranking from the `subset_array`. In other words, the `subset_array` has the ranked items, i.e., `d` has rank 1, `a` has rank 2, and `f` has rank 3. Using this information, I need to build the array in the order the values appear in the `main_array`.

For example, from the `subset_array` and `main_array` above, I need the following array.

```
desired_array = [2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3]
```

How can I do this in TypeScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest solution due to lucky requirements

```js
const main_array = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"];
const subset_array = ["d", "a", "f"];

const result = main_array.map((x) => subset_array.indexOf(x) + 1);

console.log(result);
```